# Using performance.mark() with Chrome dev tools performance tab

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome

I'd like to see my calls to `performance.mark(...)` show up on Chrome's dev tools Performance tab. All the documentation I can find online seem to refer to the no longer existing "Timeline" tab, while [the docs on the new Performance tab](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/reference) don't have anything to say about it.

In my code, I'm simply doing `performance.mark('my mark name')`. I have also tried doing the same with `console.timeStamp('my mark name')` because I saw that in some old docs as well.

How do I see these calls to `performance.mark()` on the Performance tab?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

In the new performance tab markers show up in "User Timing".
You need to use

> [performance.measure()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/measure)

to mark the start and end of your marks
like this:

```
performance.mark('myMark-start');

// your code 

performance.mark('myMark-end');
performance.measure('myPerfMarker', 'myMark-start', 'myMark-end');
```

Comment: you're the hero ^^ should be accepted answer as there is so little doc on the web, google deprecated the timestamp doc page and didn't give a link to new info...